# Gnome accelerometer not updating automatically

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, laptop, sensors, tablet

I have a convertible laptop ([HP Envy x360 15-aq015nd](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-15-aq000-x360-Convertible-PC/10862127/document/c05160683)) with Gnome.

In the live modus (on a USB, before installing), the automatic rotation worked perfectly. I think it even enabled itself when I folded the keyboard behind the screen, and disabled when folding it back to a 'normal' laptop.

But now that I have installed it to the SSD, the screen isn't rotating anymore, even when manually disabling rotation-lock (from the top-right menu).

I tried monitoring the iio with `monitor-sensor`...

```
Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: undefined)
=== No ambient light sensor
```

So the sensor is found, but not read.

I found out that I can manually trigger updating the sensor with `cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_x_raw` (or y, or z).

Only when using that command while holding the laptop in another orientation, the screen rotates, and `monitor-sensor` outputs another line. for example:

```
Accelerometer orientation changed: right-up
```

The only way to turn the screen back is rotating the laptop, and `cat` the raw output again.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my system, or with Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your research. I am having the exact same problem with my Dell Latitude 3379. My limited amount of searching yields nothing about configuring sensor updates. I don't really feel like spending the time diving into the kernel, so until some update fixes this, I am just going to run a `bash` script

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device6/in_accel_x_raw
    sleep 1s
done
```

*(Removing or modifying `sleep 1s` will make it react more quickly to a change in orientation.)*

to trigger updates. I could add it to my startup applications, but I want to remember to check if some update or condition fixes it. (I'm sure you figured this out but I want to leave a trail for the next person).

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying it to everyone. I've done a comparable thing, but with `sleep 1` which may make it more processor and battery friendly

Comment: @WilcoVerhoef I had forgotten about this post. This issue has mostly gone away for me—I suspect through system updates (Ubuntu 17.10). However, before the fixes, I discovered that this script _probably will not work_ most of the time, as the `iio` device numbers are reassigned on boot (the accelerometer may be at any `iio:device#`). A more robust script could probably be created to check the device assignments and only read the proper device, but hopefully the fixes I experienced are sufficient. Can't say that I have rigorously tested it.